# Should I mock ALL external Services in angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularfire

I'm currently getting started with angular unit testing. As the first controller I wanted to tes looked like this, I got confused.

```
angular.module('sgmPaperApp')
  .controller('AccountCtrl', function ($mdToast, user, $firebaseArray, Ref) {
var vm = this;
vm.data = user;
vm.save = saveUser;
vm.comments = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('comments').orderByChild('person').equalTo(user.$id));


function saveUser() {
  vm.data.$save().then(function () {
    $mdToast.showSimple('Data saved');
  });
}
});
```

Should I really mock all external services I use? After all that controller isn't very much more then external services and mocking the firebaseArray could be difficult.

Thanks for your advice and helping me get started with testing

Comment: Yes, otherwise you aren't **unit** testing. Do you have an actual question about your code or are you just after opinions?

Comment: I was after opinions ;) It just felt weird to mock all that. But how'd I mock the Ref service, which gives me a firebase Reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to worry about what the external dependencies do, just mock their APIs.

These are the only mocks I can see. I'm going to assume you're using Jasmine

```
var Ref, $firebaseArray, $mdToast, user, vm;

beforeEach(function() {
    Ref = jasmine.createSpyObj('Ref', ['child', 'orderByChild', 'equalTo']);
    Ref.child.and.returnValue(Ref);
    Ref.orderByChild.and.returnValue(Ref);
    Ref.equalTo.and.returnValue(Ref);

    $firebaseArray = jasmine.createSpy('$firebaseArray').and.returnValue('comments');
    $mdToast = jasmine.createSpyObj('$mdToast', ['showSimple']);
    user = jasmine.createSpyObj('user', ['$save']);
    user.$id = 'id';

    module('sgmPaperApp'); // you should consider separate modules per "thing"

    inject(function($controller) {
        vm = $controller('AccountCtrl', {
            $mdToast: $mdToast,
            user: user,
            $firebaseArray: $firebaseArray,
            Ref: Ref
        });
    });
});
```

Then you can easily create your tests

```
it('assigns a bunch of stuff on creation', function() {
    expect(vm.data).toBe(user);
    expect(vm.comments).toEqual('comments'); // that's what the mock returns

    expect(Ref.child).toHaveBeenCalledWith('comments');
    expect(Ref.orderByChild).toHaveBeenCalledWith('person');
    expect(Ref.equalTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user.$id);
    expect($firebaseArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Ref);
});
```

You can even test promise based methods like `saveUser`

```
it('saves the user and makes some toast', inject(function($q, $rootScope) {
    user.$save.and.returnValue($q.when()); // an empty, resolved promise
    vm.saveUser();
    expect(user.$save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($mdToast.showSimple).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // because the promise hasn't resolved yet

    $rootScope.$apply(); // resolves promises

    expect($mdToast.showSimple).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Data saved');
}));
```

Comment: Many thnaks, yes, I'm using jasmine and I'll read up stuff from that answer I don't understand. I do not use modules because of the yoeman generator, is there a big impact on testing?

Comment: @Isigiel in a way, yes. The `module` function bootstraps the supplied module and if you lump everything into one, you're not exactly building / testing isolated components.

Comment: @Isigiel have a look at how the [angular-seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) structures the various modules, services, directives and controllers.

Comment: Also when using that code, it seems like the original firebase service is srill used and crashes

Comment: @Isigiel I had a typo in the locals arg to `$controller` (I had `$firebadseArray`). It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

So to answer the question we need to consider what we're actually trying to do. If we are trying to **unit test**, then yes, we need to mock **all** dependencies.

Mocking your dependencies won't be hard though. You only need to mock **what you're using.**

For example, `$firebaseArray` starts off as a function that receives a paramter, we know that much:

```
var mockFirebaseArray = function(ref) {
};
```

Next, before we can finish it, we need to mock the `Ref`:

```
var mockRef = {
  child: function(path) {
    this.orderByChild = function(path) {
      this.equalTo = function(val) {
      };
      return this;
    };
    return this;
  }
};
```

With these things in place we can decide how the test will "pass". We could just use spies. Or, we could set local variables that we can assert later on our way through.

Spies are my preferred method because you can even verify they were called with specific values:

```
expect(mockFirebaseArray).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockRef.child).toHaveBeenCalledWith('comments');
```

Now, if you're wanting to write an integration test that's different. In that case I'd still use spies, but you'd actually be executing those dependencies. Generally speaking there is no need to test your dependencies because they should be tested in isolation as well. Furthermore, there is less need to test other people's API's if they are from trustworthy sources.